# How do I get a tkinter window to launch when running a program in PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm, python-idle

I recently started using PyCharm rather than IDLE for the programming course I am doing, with the promise of being able to run programs without constantly having to save them and then go to the menu to type "run in module" to do so, and to also have multiple files open in tabs to easily swap between.

While this has been good for the later, and I finally fixed a directory problem for the former, the current project I am working on involves tkinter, and PyCharm refuses to launch a tkinter window when the file is run. It can print statements fine and do calculations, but it will not launch a tkinter window. The program works fine in IDLE, but I'd rather not do all my editing in PyCharm only to constantly have to open and run it in IDLE to make the bloody window pop up. I'm using python 3.5.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: show code and error message. Did you use `root.mainloop()` in your code ? IDLE use `tkinter` and own `root.mainloop()` (to show own windows) so it could run your code too. But normally you need `root.mainloop()` to run tkinter program.

Comment: Thank you. I had a function called main() which tricked me into thinking I should already have been doing this. I added a mainloop() to the correct object and it works fine now, thank you.

Comment: One can also run programs in IDLE without having to explicitly save and use the menu.  On the General tab of the Settings dialog, select () No Prompt for Autosave Preferences.  Then use the shortcut key F5. There may be other reasons to use PyCharm, but not this one.  After a program runs (whether with F5 or the menu) and Python shifts to interactive mode (as IDLE requests upon starting Python), IDLE injects a Tcl update() call 20 times per second.  This is the same tcl function called by root.update.  The purpose is to allow one to interactively work with, learn, and develop a tk(inter) GUI.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205820379-How-to-install-Tkinter-in-PyCharm-Community-Edition-4-5-3-for-windows

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import*
tk = Tk()
btn = Button(tk, text="Click Me")
btn.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

The tk.mainloop()  [or root.mainloop() if your Tk()=root]  at the end or your code makes a little window pop up.

Hope this helps.